# What did Olaf rearrange in this scene?

Tags: frozen-ii

In Frozen II (2019), Anna confronts Kristoff in the charade game:

> Anna: I don't think Olaf should get to **rearrange**. Doesn't matter. This
>   is gonna be a cinch.

What did Olaf rearrange in this scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He rearranged his body. This is something that only he can do, which gives him an advantage, hence Anna’s comment.

Here’s the clip:

Answer (score 1):

#### Himself

He rearranges himself into various different forms, see the scene below:

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the film's [junior novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/44908905-frozen-2). In short, Olaf has a tendency, when playing charades, to rearrange his body into shapes that reflect the phrases he's trying to convey.

> ***Olaf had an advantage in playing charades because he could rearrange himself to fit any answer, and that was exactly what he did now. He pulled out his arms and legs and nose and put them in different places on his body to form different shapes and sizes.** Almost as fast as Olaf assembled himself each time, Kristoff guessed the right answer.*
>
> *“Unicorn,” Kristoff said. “Ice cream. Castle! Oaken! Teapot! Mouse! Oooh, Elsa!”*
>
> *Sven rang the bell to end the round. Time had flown! The guys cheered. They hadn’t gotten a single one wrong.*
>
> *Anna didn’t believe it was fair. “I don’t think Olaf should get to rearrange,” she said, looking pointedly at both Olaf and Kristoff. Elsa’s expression showed that she agreed. “Doesn’t matter. This is going to be a cinch. Two sisters, one mind.”*

It would appear that this is not the first time he's pulled this stunt, nor will it be the last.